# Insert into table without duplicates

Tags: sql

I have a Table A from where I have to copy Data to Table B. Now problem is In both table A and Table B there is a column ID which is primary key and can't be null.Table A is having Duplicates. Can any one tell me How to insert Data into Table B from Table A without Duplicates?

Comment: Add some sample table data as well as the expected result. Formatted text please, not images,.

Comment: and also db platform

Comment: How (column ID which is primary key and can't be null.Table A is having Duplicates) ? Duplicate on ID? or other columns? ID is primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be something like

```
INSERT INTO TableA(ID) SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TableB B LEFT JOIN TableA A ON A.ID = B.ID WHERE A.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: I can't use distinct over ID Column as ID is having Distinct Records. But other columns are having Duplicates. I was trying with Row_Number over partition By. But still problem not solving

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **DISTINCT** function in a select statement to remove duplicates.
In the example I'm going to assume that both tables have 3 columns called **ID**, **Name** and **Surname**:

```
insert into tableB (ID, Name, Surname)
select
    distinct(ID) as ID
    ,Name
    ,Surname
from tableA
;
```

Please note that the **DISTINCT** function will provide distinct rows.